# How to get the XML node name?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, serialization

I am doing a challenge thing but I am struggling to get the name of the XML node, "folder". I am trying to return all folders that begin with 'u'.

I want to output to be "Uninstall Information" and "Users" but I still have all the XML structure.

Any help would be great.

```
 class Program
    {
        public static IEnumerable<string> FolderNames(string xml, char startingLetter)
        {
            List<string> elem = new List<string>();
            List<int> list = new List<int>();

            XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmldoc.LoadXml(xml);

            XmlNodeList temp = xmldoc.SelectNodes("folder");

             elem.Add(temp[0].InnerXml);
             Console.WriteLine(elem[0]);

            return elem;
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
                "<folder name=\"c\">" +
                "<folder name=\"program files\">" +
                "<folder name=\"uninstall information\" />" +
                "</folder>" +
                "<folder name=\"users\" />" +
                "</folder>";

            Program.FolderNames(xml, 'u');

            //foreach (string name in Program.FolderNames(xml, 'u'))
                //Console.WriteLine(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend reading something about XML... "Node name" is completely different thing from what you seem to be looking for. Basic Wikipeda article may be good start https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Key_terminology to improve your post by [edit]. Also there are likely many duplicates of whatever task you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code shows how to use XPath expression to select folder names starting with particular letter from your XML. This XPath consists of following parts:

`//folder` selects all "folder" XML elements (including subfolders)
`/@name` selects attribute "name" of those elements
`[starts-with(., 'u')]` is condition that selects only attributes starting with specified letter

```
public static IEnumerable<string> FolderNames(string xml, char startingLetter)
{
    List<string> elem = new List<string>();

    XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmldoc.LoadXml(xml);

    foreach (XmlAttribute folderName in xmldoc.SelectNodes("//folder/@name[starts-with(., '"+ startingLetter +"')]"))
    {
        elem.Add(folderName.Value);
        Console.WriteLine(folderName.Value);
    }

    return elem;
}
```